# How to return type Promise<void> or Promise<any>?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

In TypeScript
How can I return a promise of either type
`Promise<void>`
or
`Promise<any>`

I'ved tried

- `Promise<void | any>`
- `Promise<void> | Promise<any>`

The resulting error is for `Promise<void | any>`:

`error TS2794: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. Did you forget to include 'void' in your type argument to 'Promise'?`
[image]

I ran into this error when upgrading from Angular 11 -> 12. This TypeScript version now throws this error when Promise type isn't provided.

See example type error in below...

```js
type SpecialPromise = (number: number) => Promise<void>;

const returnsSomething: SpecialPromise = (number: number) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(number), 2000));
};
const returnsVoid: SpecialPromise = (number: number) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000));
};
Promise.all([
  returnsSomething(Math.random()),
  returnsVoid(Math.random())
]).then((numbers) => console.log(numbers));
```

The problem is when I create a new promise it by default expects a type.
void (nothing) is not a type.

```js
new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;
```

A simple fix is to specify the type when creating the promise.

```js
new Promise<void>
```

But still I get the error if I decide to use:

```js
new Promise<void | any>
```

[image: Edit TypeScript (forked)]

Comment: Does `ActionMetadata` extend `ActionTrigger`? Please post a [mcve] and the complete error message.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the question to be general and gave an example.

Comment: That error message appears to be about a call to the `resolve` function, not to the type declaration. Could you please post the full code in your question?

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to resolve a promise with `undefined` like `Promise.resolve(undefined)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want Promise<undefined|any>